# where did turtle_tf_sensor.launch go?

Tags: ros, transform, ros-diamondback, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tf tutorial page:
[uisng time stamped datatypes with tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter)
the first line says to run a launch file that does not exist in diamondback.

roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_sensor.launch

I would be really nice to see this example.  Any ideas where it has gone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9512/where-did-turtle_tf_sensor.launch-go?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2011-03-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It moved to the geometry_tutorials stack.  You need to install that stack.  If you're using debs you will need ros-diamondback-geometry-tutorials

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rlinsalata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2578/rlinsalata/) on 2012-06-22**:
Is this still the case?  I can't seem to find the launch files for the mentioned tf::MessageFilter tutorial, or the Debugging tf tutorial right before it (start_debug_demo.launch), but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-12-28**:
@rlinsalata I'm also wondering where start_debug_demo.launch is hiding.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-07**:
I can't find start_debug_demo.launch either